# Import data with leading zeros - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, leading-zero

I'm trying to import data into a table. I'm doing a bulk insert. I've created the table using a CREATE statement where all fields are nvarchar(max). I cannot understand why when the import is done, the data with leading zeros has been changed to scientific notation. Why does it not stay as text and preserve the leading zeros?

Comment: What are you using to do the bulk insert? How have you specified the type of the input? Almost no mechanisms that do bulk insert care about the type in your *destination table* -- they just leave it to SQL Server to perform the conversion implicitly.

Comment: I'm using a BULK INSERT in SQL Server Management Studio. Is there a way to import where the type of the destination table is taken into account?

Comment: Why is *every* **column** (SQL Server doesn't have "fields") a `varchar(MAX)`? Do you *really* need 2GB of storage space for every piece of data?

Comment: What is your source data? I'm guessing, seeing as you are getting scientific notation, that it's Excel?

Comment: @Larnu Good point. Just wasn't sure how many characters are contained within the fields. As far as I've read, it stores as nvarchar(4000) unless more space is needed. Thanks for the correction in my terminology. I still need an answer about leading zeros.

Comment: @MatthewDarwin It's .bulk files. Is that from Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you define the number of zeros that do you want and then make an update. Here is an example with 10 zeros.

```
create table #leadingZeros(uglynumber nvarchar(max),handsomenumber nvarchar(max),nicenumber nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO #leadingZeros VALUES(1000000,0000123,0500000)

SELECT * FROM #leadingZeros
--OUTPUT:
--uglynumber    handsomenumber  nicenumber
--1000000   123     500000
UPDATE #leadingZeros SET 
uglynumber=RIGHT('0000000000'+uglynumber,10)
,handsomenumber=RIGHT('0000000000'+handsomenumber,10)
,nicenumber=RIGHT('0000000000'+nicenumber,10)

SELECT * FROM #leadingZeros
--OUTPUT
--uglynumber    handsomenumber  nicenumber
--0001000000    0000000123  0000500000
```